# reducing polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm stuck with a theorem I'm trying to prove, which says that for any $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $g,h\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.th. $f=gh$, there is some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that both $\alpha g$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha}h$ are in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It seems like just a few lines, and I tried to experiment with some of the functions being primitive, but I am not getting anywhere. What is the trick here?

Comment: Presumably $f = gh$.

Comment: Google "Gauss's Lemma".

Comment: Oh, now it all makes sense. To be clear - it's not true as currently written. For example, taking $g = \frac{1}{5}x$ and $h = \frac{2}{3}x$, you get that both $p > q$ and $q > p$ if $\alpha = \frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: yes, sorry, $f=gh$, and this $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: well, it is true as currently written. in that example, $gh=\frac{1}{5}x \frac{2}{3}x = \frac{2}{15}x^2\notin \mathbb{Z}[x]$. But thanks for the hint on the name!.